# Setting tintColor on UITabBAr causes Application to Crash

Tags: objective-c, ios4

I have the following code in my `application:DidFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` where I attempt to set tab bar tint colour:

```
UIColor *colour = [UAColors getSeasonalColour];

self.tabBarController.tabBar.tintColor = colour;    // SIGABORT here
[colour release];
```

`getSeasonalColours` is:

```
+(UIColor *)getSeasonalColour {
    UIColor *seasonalColour = 0;

    if ( [UADates isSpring:[NSDate date]] )
        seasonalColour = [UIColor greenColor];
    else if ( [UADates isSummer:[NSDate date]] )
        seasonalColour = [UIColor blueColor];
    else if ( [UADates isAutumn:[NSDate date]] )
        seasonalColour = [UIColor orangeColor];
    else if ( [UADates isWinter:[NSDate date]] )
        seasonalColour = [UIColor redColor];
    else
        seasonalColour = [UIColor blackColor];

    return seasonalColour;
}
```

Right now `UADates` is only a stub that returns true for `isWinter`.

Why would this cause a crash?  Using the same `getSeasonalColours` works perfectly fine when I set the `tintColor` on a navigation bar.

Comment: What happens if you replace `colour` in the offending line with `[UIColor redColor]`? This should help isolate the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting a tab bar's tint color is only available starting with iOS 5 (and thus will crash on iOS 4 and earlier), while navigation bar tint colors have been around since iPhone OS 2.0.

Comment: That would be the reason.  Accepted.

Answer (score 2):

`[colour release]` should not be there, since your colours are all autoreleased. Are you sure *that* isn't the line that is crashing?

Comment: Tried this.  Still crashes, but still helpful.